# Override method for default RESTFUL Routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, resources, routes

Given a line something like below in `routes.rb`

```
map.resources :users
```

The routes generated might be something like this:

```
      users GET    /users(.:format)           {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
            POST   /users(.:format)           {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Is there any way to change the default HTTP method of `POST /users` mapping to `{:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}` to the HTTP method being used to be a `PUT` instead?

`rake routes` would then generate something like this:

```
      users GET    /users(.:format)           {:controller=>"users", :action=>"index"}
            PUT    /users(.:format)           {:controller=>"users", :action=>"create"}
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  {:controller=>"users", :action=>"edit"}
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"}
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"}
```

I understand that this wouldn't be correct for RESTful routing, I'm just wondering if it is possible to change the HTTP methods used by these routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly add a route to accept a `/users` with PUT to create users but it won't replace the existing POST route.

```
map.connect '/users(.:format)', 
   :controller => 'users', 
   :action => 'create', 
   :conditions => { :method => :put }
```

You can also add a new route for creating users by adding `:member => { :create => :put }` which will result in a route like this:

```
create_users  PUT  /users/create(.:format)  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
```

but I appreciate that that doesn't address exactly what you are asking!

Comment: This is basically what I have done so far to get around it, was hoping I could do away without the extra route and just change the method used by the route created with map.resources.

Answer (score 1):

Defining

```
map.resources :users, :member =>{:create => :put}
```

Will do it for `:users`.  I am not sure about a default override like with method names in action controller like:

```
config.action_controller.resources_path_names = { :new => "create", 
        :edit => "change" }
```

Which is what you may have been asking.